# Weather stripping prevents automatic trunk opening

Tags: trunk

I have an automatic trunk release on my key fob. Pressing the button unlocks the trunk properly. However, the trunk lid sticks to the weather stripping and the lid rarely pops up. Pulling the trunk open you can hear the sound of the strip peeling away from the trunk lid, like the sound of pulling Scotch tape. I don't know what causes it.  Humidity? Is there something I can do to keep it from sticking?

Answer (score 0):

Try Gummi Pledge-it is used by people like me with metal roof convertibles to keep the rubbers supple-yours are getting hard and sticky from the humidity.

Comment: Ill give it a shot in the next few days.  Is this the best by far?  Or will any similar product work as well?

Comment: I guess anything that makes the rubber more supple would work-the stuff i use is what MB recommend

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can't comment so I guess this is going to be an answer. I would try rubbing down the weather stripping with some Honda shin-etsu Grease, make sure the weatherstripping is clean as well.